# Join Eloquent Model with condition

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the three Models `Post`, `Page` and `Category`.

Each `Page` is assigned to one `Category` and each `Post` is assigned to one `Page`.

I have already defined the relationships in the models. What I want to do now is to use Eloquent ORM to get all `Post`-objects that are from a `Page` with a certain `Category`. So basically, in SQL I would need to do it like this

```
select p.* from posts p INNER JOIN pages pa ON pa.id = p.page_id where p.created_time > '2015-08-18 00:00:00' and pa.categories_id = 1 and p.isVisible = 1 order by p.total_count desc limit 100
```

I'm now somehow trying to do the same with Eloquent, but I'm stuck. My current code looks like this

```
// Getting all the top posts from facebook for today.
/** @var Builder $topPosts */
$topPosts = Post::where('created_time', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString());
if ($type !== null) {
    $topPosts = $topPosts->where('type', $type);
}
return $topPosts->orderBy('total_count', 'desc')
    ->visible()
    ->take($limit)
    ->get();
```

Now, I wanted to add the category, but I don't know how to do it. I tried these steps here:

```
$topPosts = $topPosts->with(['page' => function($query) use($categoryId){
    $query->where('page_categories_id', $categoryId);
}]);
```

and this one

```
$topPosts = $topPosts->with('page')->where('page_categories_id', $categoryId);
```

but none of them worked. How would I achieve that? I always get the error message

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `created_time` > 2015-08-18 00:00:00 and `categories_id` = 1 and `isVisible` = 1 order by `total_count` desc limit 100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `whereHas()` in place your `with()` statement there (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

This should work, and is basically just querying Posts with associated Pages with the particular category_id. I haven't included your ordering and things..

```
$posts = Post::where('created_time', '>', Carbon::today()) // Eloquent shouldn't actually need the toDateTimeString()
            ->with('page') // leave this in to eager load the page
            ->whereHas('page', function($query) use ($categoryId) {
                $query->where('page_categories_id', $categoryId);
            })
            ->get();
```